# What does the RSI abbreviation stand for?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

I'm reading [an article](http://www.jon.gold/2016/06/declarative-design-tools/) about innovative design tooling from the perspective of divergence and convergence. Everything had been pretty much straightforward until I stumbled upon this "RSI" abbreviation. The context is as follows:

> "The declarative example is neat, composable and super readable; the imperative one messy and full of manual array shuffling.
>   This might seem tangential to the example of our poor junior designer copying & pasting artboards until **RSI** sets in, but it’s an important headspace to be in whilst considering our design tooling."

The only guesses I can come up with are the relative strength index and Research Science Institute. I will greatly appreciate if someone could shed the light on this.

Thanks!

Comment: What research did you do, to try to find the answer? Try googling *rsi*...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repetitive Stress Injury a.k.a. [Repetitive Strain Injury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetitive_strain_injury).  It is a somewhat broader medical condition than, although in the same class of medical conditions as, carpal tunnel syndrome, tendonitis and tennis elbow.

It is one of the most common injury types for office workers, students, musicians, video game players, and people who do fine craft work. My wife suffered from the condition after having a job in a library pressing an "approved" or "rejected" stamp heavily on one invoice after another eight hours a day, five days a week.